# Scenekit, why my car while running on the street collide on the air

Tags: scenekit, game-physics, scnnode, collider

still experimenting some new stuff on SceneKit but I can't find the reason why my car while running on the street suddenly collide with something I can't visualize.like a wall...
What could be this issue?
See the video below:

[image: collide]

Here my street, I can't see any obstacle...what going on here..

[image: street]

I load my street whit the following code:

```
  func loadStreet(){
        let street = loadAssetWithName(nameFile: "streetV1", nameNode: "street", type: "usdz", scale: SCNVector3(3,3,3))
       
        street.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)
        street.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, deg2rad(270), 0)
        let body = SCNPhysicsBody.static()
        body.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: street,options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.keepAsCompound: false,SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron ])
        body.categoryBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue //2 int, assegnato solo a quel oggetto
        body.collisionBitMask = BodyType.car.rawValue  //1 con cosa puo collidere
        body.allowsResting = true
        body.restitution = 0.1
        body.friction = 0.5
        body.rollingFriction = 0
        street.physicsBody = body
        street.name = "street"
        self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(street)
    }
```

```
 func loadVeichleFromFile(nameFile: String, nameNodeChassis: String, type: String, scale: SCNVector3, scene: SCNScene, wheelRadius: CGFloat)->SCNNode{
        let chassisNode = loadAssetWithName(nameFile: nameFile, nameNode: nameNodeChassis, type: type, scale: scale)
        chassisNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)

        let body = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
        body.categoryBitMask = BodyType.car.rawValue // what is it
        
//        body.collisionBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue // what can collide
//        body.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue
        body.allowsResting = false
        body.mass = 8
        body.restitution = 0.1
        body.friction = 0.5
        body.rollingFriction = 0
        chassisNode.physicsBody = body
        // Load the wheel
        // make sure the name of the empty node for the wheel
        let wheelnode0 = chassisNode.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FL", recursively: true)!
        let wheelnode1 = chassisNode.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FR", recursively: true)!
        let wheelnode2 = chassisNode.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RL", recursively: true)!
        let wheelnode3 = chassisNode.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RR", recursively: true)!
        
        //pos
        let wheel0 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode0)
        let wheel1 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode1)
        let wheel2 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode2)
        let wheel3 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode3)

        wheel0.suspensionRestLength = 0.5
        wheel1.suspensionRestLength = 0.5
        wheel2.suspensionRestLength = 0.5
        wheel3.suspensionRestLength = 0.5
        
        wheel0.suspensionStiffness = 1
        wheel1.suspensionStiffness = 1
        wheel2.suspensionStiffness = 1
        wheel3.suspensionStiffness = 1
        
        wheel0.suspensionDamping = 2.8
        wheel1.suspensionDamping = 2.8
        wheel2.suspensionDamping = 2.8
        wheel3.suspensionDamping = 2.8
        
        wheel0.radius = wheelRadius
        wheel1.radius = wheelRadius
        wheel2.radius = wheelRadius
        wheel3.radius = wheelRadius
        
        
        let halfheight = (wheelnode0.boundingBox.max.y - wheelnode0.boundingBox.min.y)/2
        var w0 = wheelnode0.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode) // 0.7,0.1,1.3
        w0 = w0 + SCNVector3Make(-w0.x*2, halfheight, 0) // posizione del wheelLocator_FL * 2 (per spostarsi altra parte della macchina),
        wheel0.connectionPosition = w0
        var w1 = wheelnode1.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode) // -0.7,0.1,1.3
        w1 = w1 + SCNVector3Make(-w1.x*2, halfheight, 0)
        wheel1.connectionPosition = w1
        var w2 = wheelnode2.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode)
        w2 = w2 + SCNVector3Make(-w2.x*2, halfheight, 0) // segno negativo perche ruote vengono caricate inverse
        wheel2.connectionPosition = w2
        var w3 = wheelnode3.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode)
        w3 = w3 + SCNVector3Make(-w3.x*2, halfheight, 0)
        wheel3.connectionPosition = w3

        physicsVehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassisNode.physicsBody!, wheels: [wheel1,wheel0,wheel3,wheel2]) // ordine importante per rispettare FL,FR

        scene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(physicsVehicle)
        return chassisNode
    }
```

can't understand why my car running smoothly until the beginning of the ramp than suddenly looks like there is a wall...

what could be??

Thanks

Comment: what you mean? here is a s straight line..I'm not crashing into nothing .. is more a physic simulation issue

Comment: This can happen, when the vehicle switches from one geometry object to another. It produces kind of invisible bump. How do your both geometry objects match together? Is there some overlapping or a gap between? You could try to make one single geometry out of it. And how fast is your car at the time when it reaches the ramp?

Answer (score 0):

Replace body.collisionBitMask = BodyType.car.rawValue  //1 con cosa puo collidere with a contactTestBitMask.

What does your code do upon collision? I suspect your car is bouncing because it is colliding with the road.